# insert excel file into sql (selected data)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an excel file (currently look like attached image) wanted to import it into my db.

[image]

currently my query look like this

```
INSERT INTO [inSharePoint] (processingDate, [url], [sharepointName], [ownerEmail], [secondaryOwnerEmail], [lastUpdateDate], [totalQuotaInMB], [totalStorageInMB], [storageUsedInPercentage], [lockStatus], [siteType], [spVersion])
    VALUES ('{processingDate}', @url, @sharepointName, @ownerEmail, @secondaryOwnerEmail, @lastUpdateDate, @totalQuotaInMB, @totalStorageInMB, @storageUsedInPercentage, @lockStatus, @siteType, @spVersion)
```

but what if i wanted to insert the same file but the only difference is for my column `[LockStatus]`, I ONLY want with the status `nolock` to be insert and not others status (No readonly and noaccess)

i am really new to sql hope somebody could explain it thank you

Comment: You want all the columns to say 'nolock' or you only want to insert the rows which have a LockStatus of 'nolock'?

Comment: What are you using to read the Excel file?

Comment: No, i don't want to convert it. I want to insert row LockStatus with only "nolock" status @dbajtr

Comment: I map the file using mongoDB. and driver call xlsxWriter @squillman

Comment: Ok.  How are you getting the data from mongo to SQL Server?

Comment: You can use SSIS to do this pretty easily

Comment: i'm using node js, is it affecting the query? i'm sorry, i am really new to these technology, just trying to experimenting myself. @squillman

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel Marcus mentioned, you could use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) to do this pretty easily if you have it available.

In your current solution it looks like you're processing the Excel data row by row in which case you'd need to check the data in your NodeJS code using an IF statement and only do the insert if `LockStatus` = `nolock`.

Or, you could use a mongo query to pull only the data where `LockStatus` = `nolock` and send that data to SQL Server.  I'm not familiar with querying mongo, though, so not sure what that would look like.

Comment: OK i understood, currently looking for SSIS. Thank you very much for the hint! I will try it @squillman

Comment: Sounds good!  If you're using SQL Server Express (or LocalDB) you won't have access to SSIS.  You'll need at least SQL Server Standard

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to do this!

```
Sub InsertARecord()
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stCon As String, stSQL As String
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

stCon = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=JOEY"
cnt.ConnectionString = stCon
stSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (FieldNames)"
stSQL = stSQL & "VALUES (ActualValues)"
stSQL = stSQL & "WHERE lockStatus = 'nolock'"

cnt.Open
rst.Open stSQL, cnt, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, see this URL.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Introduction